# Facetwp pagination url

Tags: wordpress, facetwp

I`m using the FacetWP plugin, and I want to rename URL slug when the user clicks on pager pagination.
For example user clicks to get products on 2 pages and the URL looks like /?_paged=2

I need to change paged into a new text. It is possible?

Comment: Nope. Facetwp only allows two URL structures `_` and `fwp_`. [Here's the documentation](https://facetwp.com/help-center/developers/the-facetwp-url/#changing-the-url-prefix) - You could *technically* change it in the database, but will probably not work.

Comment: I'm adding another comment because after rereading, you want to change `paged` not the `_`. Again, I don't think this is possible, since FWP is simply using the WP built in WP_Query to get the next page of results. You'd have to change how FWP works to trigger a pagination.

Comment: maybe somehow i can translate that? I need to translate paged into my language